# How to query 2 tables on a date column ,if matching date doesn't exist then we have to join with next maximum date

Tags: hiveql, impala

I have 2 tables like below

TABLE 1

```
id   DOB         name
1   01/01/1990   victor
2   01/01/1991   deb
3   01/01/1992   Mat
```

Table 2

```
id   Date         amount
1   01/01/1990    100
2   12/11/1990    700
2   12/30/1990    455
2   01/02/2014      7000
3   12/30/1991    800
3   06/22/1991    332
```

I want output as below

```
id   DOB         name.    amount
1   01/01/1990   victor   100
2   01/01/1991   deb      455
3   01/01/1992   Mat      800
```

We have to join on id columns and DOB column in table1 and date column in table2 . If Dates don't match then we have to join on next maximum date column

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you mean by 'next max date' ? - for deb - what should be correct data? is it going to be 7000 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query -
I assumed, in case of dob doesnt match to date column, we should pick up amount tied to maximum date. please clarify so i can change sql accordingly.

```
select id, dob, name, amount 
from
(select a.id,a,dob,a.name,b.amount,b.date,
row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.id ,b.date desc) rn
from
table1 a
left join table2 b on a.id = b.id ) rs
where case when date = dob then 1 else rs.rn end=1
```